# How to perform a DELETE request without return type or Callback? [Retrofit]

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit

I need perform a DELETE request using Retrofit. So, my code snippet of the interface looks like this:

```
@DELETE("/api/item/{id}")
void deleteItem(@Path("id") int itemId);
```

But I get the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ApiItem.deleteItem: Must have
>   either a return type or Callback as last argument.

However, according to the rules of Rest API, I shouldn't receive any response to DELETE request. How should I specify it in the interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You **have to add Callback** as last argument in request method if you want to have void method. You can use`Callback<Response>`.

You have to change this:

```
@DELETE("/api/item/{id}")
void deleteItem(@Path("id") int itemId);
```

to :

```
@DELETE("/api/item/{id}")
void deleteItem(@Path("id") int itemId, Callback<Response> callback);
```

Or you can return just `Response`

```
@DELETE("/api/item/{id}")
Response deleteItem(@Path("id") int itemId);
```

Comment: And Overridden method in the case with Callback should be like this? `RestApiStorage.me().getApiItem().deleteItem(itemId, null);`

Comment: No use new Callback<Response>(){...method...} and ignore response

Comment: Use Void as return type

Comment: I am using void as return type: '@DELETE("books/{id}")
    void deleteBook(@Path("id") int itemId);'  I get a error: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service methods cannot return void.
                                                                                     for method LibraryService.deleteBook.** Any suggestion on this? Thanks.

Comment: By using the suggestion about: ''@DELETE("books/{id}")
    void deleteBook(@Path("id") int bookId, Callback<Response> callback);'' I get the same error: **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service methods cannot return void. for method LibraryService.deleteBook. **

Answer (score 5):

In Retrofit 2.0, You can use Call interface for the result of your request as below.

```
@DELETE("/api/item/{id}")
Call<Response> deleteItem(@Path("id") int itemId);

...

Call<Response> call = YourServiceInstance.deleteItem(10);
call.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
...
});
```

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but, which Response? OkHttp's Response? Retrofit's is templated...

Comment: OK Http response object

Comment: If using Retrofit's response, it will get error message:""'retrofit2.Response' is not a valid response body type. Did you mean ResponseBody?\n"
              + "    for method CallMethod.badType1""

Comment: @BurtK, this was the only one that did not error, but now response.body () returns null me.
Both Call <Response> When to Call <MyClassReturn>. Some light?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, possibly updated given it's now 2018.

Comment: I got this error Response must include generic type (e.g., Response<String>)

Answer (score 3):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "manage-feed", hasBody = true)
Call<ResponseBody> deletePost(@Field("post_id") Integer postId, @Field("share_id") Integer sharedMapId);
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation please

Comment: This is the method for delete where you put methods in interface

Comment: you save my life, thanks it worked for me i had to use @HTTP(method = "DELETE", hasBody = true) instead of @DELETE

Answer (score 0):

```
    @HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "/api/item/{id}", hasBody = false)
fun deleteItemId(
@Path("id") id: Int
) : Call<YourResponse>

hasBody = 
true -> if api has request body
false -> if api has not a request body
```