# Unable to get json string as response in Retrofit 2.0 android

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

This is not a duplicate question.
I am using Retrofit 2.0 and json for network tasks.
Also I am not using GSON to parse json instead I am using simple JsonObject and JsonArray to get model objects from json string.
Firstly guide me which retrofit converter must be used for above scenario.

Secondly, I am not able to get json string as response string.

I tried two approaches - 
Approach 1 - I used Call< Void >. In this case the response.body() returns null though status code is 200.

Approach 2 - I used Call< ResponseBody >. In this case call.enqueue methods call 'on failure method' instead of 'onSuccess' and also the response body is null.
The status code is 200 in this case also.

Please suggest how to get the json string as response from retrofit 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use `JsonObject` instead of `Void` or `ResponseBody`. Your code should be

```
Call<JsonObject> getCall = request.getDataCall();
getCall.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

**Note** : make sure you are using `com.google.gson.JsonObject`

Comment: Thanks. Its working. Also can you please tell me when to use void and response body.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970476/how-to-perform-a-delete-request-without-return-type-or-callback-retrofit) can give you clear idea about it.

Comment: ok i ll read it. One more help if possible....Help me regarding this post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38877535/unable-to-parse-different-json-format-string-via-gson